# Ternary operator returns 0 instead of character string

Tags: spring, thymeleaf, spring-el

I am in the middle of rewriting my Spring MVC application from JSP pages to Thymeleaf templates. I am however experiencing the following problem.

When I am using ternary operator with results that are of different types namely `java.lang.String` and `java.lang.Integer` the string is always presented as `0` if the condition in ternary operator is not fulfilled.

```
<p th:text="#{free_transfers} + ': ' + (${i ne T(java.lang.Integer).MAX_VALUE}
? ${i} : '∞')">Cumulated free transfers: ∞</p>
```

The resulting HTML is however

```
<p>Free transfers: 0</p>
```

if `i` is equal `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

At first I thought that this is because of the fact that the second argument is of type `int` so I explicitly added the conversion to character string.

```
<p th:text="#{free_transfers} + ': ' + (${i ne T(java.lang.Integer).MAX_VALUE}
? ${#strings.toString(i)} : '∞')">Cumulated free transfers: ∞</p>
```

however this does change anything and the result is still

```
<p>Free transfers: 0</p>
```

Does anybody have any idea how to achieve the expected result

```
<p>Free transfers: ∞</p>
```

?

I have also tried these ones but without any success.

```
|#{free_transfers}: ${i ne T(Integer).MAX_VALUE ? #strings.toString(i) : "∞"}|

|#{free_transfers}: ${i ne T(Integer).MAX_VALUE ? i : "∞"}|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be all within one `${}` expression also you might not need `toString` just use `i`

```
  ${i ne T(java.lang.Integer).MAX_VALUE ? i : '∞'}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this returns exactly the same result, namely `0`.

Comment: The problem turned out to be somewhere completely else. In fact the value `i` was equal `0` so no surprise the displayed value was `0`. +1 for simplifying the expression.

Comment: @jagger glad you figured it out

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem at the beginning with the order of "+" sign and ":" sign. This one works:

```
<p th:text="'Free transfers :'+ (${i ne T(java.lang.Integer).MAX_VALUE}
? ${i} : '∞')">Cumulated free transfers: ∞</p>
```

Comment: Well, in fact I do not have a hardcoded text there, so `+` has to stay where it is. I wanted to simplify the example by putting a hardcoded text there. I am reading the text from a message bundle with `#{free_transfers}`. I updated the question.

Comment: I have just checked it with hardcoded text. It does not work anyway. I am still getting `0`.

Comment: I get a parse expression error for your line. There is a problem with the number of apostrophes for me. That's what I corrected. Could it be a typo?

Comment: I updated the question, it should be OK right now, without the hardcoded text and with `#{free_transfers}`.

Comment: If I define i as Integer.MAX_VALUE then my code returns: "Free transfers :∞" could it be a version difference?

Comment: I am using the newest version of Spring Boot `1.2.7.RELEASE`. The artifact for Thymeleaf is `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf`.

Comment: Exactly the same version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93064/discussion-between-jagger-and-peter).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in fact in the part that provided the value of `i` variable. Instead of `Integer.MAX_VALUE` it provided `0`, so no wonder it was displayed as `0`.